# is the value at this key an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've written the following function to return the average of all the numbers of an array at a given key in an object:

```
var obj = {
  key: [1, 2, 3]
};
function getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (!(key in obj)) {
    return 0;
  } else if (obj[key].length === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
      total += obj[key][i];
    }
    return total/(obj[key].length);
  }
}
console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, "key"));
```

Everything is fine, except I need to add one more else if statement before the else statement that checks if the value at that key is an array. If it isn't, it should return 0. I have looked up ways to do this but none of them have worked.

Answer (score 4):

With `instanceof`:

```js
var obj = {
  k1: [1, 2, 3],
  k2: null,
  k3: "string",
  k4: 5
};

function getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (!(obj[key] instanceof Array) || obj[key].length == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
      total += obj[key][i];
    }
    return total / (obj[key].length);
  }
}
console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, "k1"))
console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, "k2"))
console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, "k3"))
console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, "k4"))
console.log(getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, "k5"))
```

Comment: Good! You could even use a `reduce` to calculate the total!!

Answer (score 0):

To check if a particular property is an array or not, use 'instanceof' operator.

In your case, add the below condition.

```
else if(! (obj.key instanceof Array)) {
return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you've looked up ways but they haven't worked, what have you tried and what problems did you find?

There is the [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) function, which will return a boolean.

```
Array.isArray([]); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.isArray(obj[key])

```
var obj = {
  key: [1, 2, 3]
};

function getAverageOfElementsAtProperty(obj, key) {

  if(!(key in obj)){
    return 0;
  }

  if(!Array.isArray(obj[key])){
    return 0;
  }

  if(obj[key].length === 0){
    return 0;
  }

  return obj[key].reduce(function(op1, op2){
       return op1 + op2;
  },  0)/obj[key].length
}
```